# How to build and publish a crate containing generated code

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

### Summary

I have a git repo containing protobuf definitions. I want to create a Python package (this part is working) and a Rust crate (this is not working) containing the code generated from these protobuf definitions.

### Problem

The problem is that Cargo doesn't seem to like that I placed the `proto` directory outside of the `Cargo.toml` tree. I don't want to move the protos inside of the `Cargo.toml` tree, because the protos are supposed to be shared with the `python` tree and this would get confusing.

This is why in the build script, I am checking for two relative parent directories for the proto files: one when running `cargo check` (where the code remains where it is now) and one when running `cargo package` (where the code gets buried somewhere inside `target/`).

This two-directory-check workaround works locally, but fails when publishing the crate, because the generated code isn't published. When I try to use the crate, the build script gets run again, which is now missing the proto definitions. But I don't want to ship the protos, just the hand-written and the generated source code.

### Question

What is the best way to package and publish the generated code, without shipping the protos with them?
I would prefer not to check in the generated code into git.

### Details

The directory structure looks like this:

```
src
├── proto
│   └── helloworld.proto
├── python
│   ├── my-msgs
│   │   ├── generated
│   │   │   ├── <generated code>
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
└── rust
    └── my-msgs
        ├── build.rs
        ├── Cargo.lock
        ├── Cargo.toml
        └── src
            ├── lib.rs
            └── test
                ├── helloworld.rs
                └── mod.rs
```

I am using `protobuf-codegen` and a build script as [recommended in the documentation](https://docs.rs/protobuf-codegen/latest/protobuf_codegen/#example).

`build.rs`:

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn find_proto_files(input_dir: &Path) -> impl Iterator<Item = PathBuf> {
    // given a directory, return the proto files in it
    let dir_read_result = fs::read_dir(input_dir);
    match dir_read_result {
        Ok(it) => it
            .map(|it| it.expect("Unable to read directory entry").path())
            .filter(|it| match it.extension() {
                Some(e) => e == "proto",
                None => false,
            })
            .map(|it| {
                Path::new(&it).to_owned()
            }),
        Err(err) => panic!(
            "Unable to read directory contents of {}: {:?}",
            input_dir.display(),
            err
        ),
    }
}

fn determine_input_dir() -> Option<PathBuf> {
    let candidates = ["../../proto", "../../../../../proto"];
    match candidates.iter().map(Path::new).find(|it| it.is_dir()) {
        Some(it) => Some(it.to_owned()),
        None => {
            eprintln!(
                "Unable to find directory containing proto files. Checked for {:?}",
                candidates
            );
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    if let Some(input_dir) = determine_input_dir() {
        println!("Reading proto files from {}", input_dir.display());
        protobuf_codegen::Codegen::new()
            .protoc()
            .includes(&[
                input_dir.to_owned(),
                Path::new("/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/").to_owned(),
            ])
            .inputs(find_proto_files(&input_dir))
            .cargo_out_dir("generated")
            .run_from_script();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may symlink the `.proto`-files to effectively share those files in a single git repo and between what both Python and Cargo consider independent projects

Comment: Is there a reason `src/proto` can't be a git-submodule of `src/rust/my-msgs`?

Comment: Aside: `candidates` does not need to be a vector or contain strings, `["../../proto", "../..…"]` would work for it just as well and has 3 useless allocations less.

Comment: @user2722968 I know of that option, but some of my colleagues are using Windows and symlinks are a mess on that platform, that's why I'd like not to use them

Comment: @cafce25 Ease of use. Some of my colleagues are not very apt in using git and for this reason I would like to avoid submodules if possible. Thanks for the hint with the useless vector, I will improve it right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually came up with my own solution using workspaces.

1. Setup a workspace with two sub-packages
2. One as a library, this will contain the generated code
3. One as a binary, this will host the code generator

In the binary one, put the code from `build.rs` into `main.rs` and make it usable from the command line.

In the library one, package the generated code.

Directory layout:

```
├── proto
│   └── helloworld.proto
├── python
│   ├── <snip>
└── rust
    ├── Cargo.toml
    ├── generator
    │   ├── Cargo.toml
    │   └── src
    │       └── main.rs
    ├── mymsgs
    │   ├── Cargo.toml
    │   └── src
    │       ├── generated
    │       │   ├── helloworld.rs
    │       │   └── mod.rs
    │       ├── lib.rs
    │       └── test
    │           ├── helloworld.rs
    │           └── mod.rs
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

The generator looks something like this:

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::io::Error;

use clap::Parser;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(name = "generator")]
#[command(long_about = None)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Directory containing the protobuf files
    #[arg(short, long, value_parser = dir_parser, value_name = "DIR")]
    protos: PathBuf,

    /// Directory to write the generated code to
    #[arg(short, long, value_parser = dir_parser, value_name = "DIR")]
    output: PathBuf,
}

/// Parses and validates str arguments as directories for use with command line argument parser
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `arg_value`: argument value given on command line
///
/// returns: Result<PathBuf, String>
///
fn dir_parser(arg_value: &str) -> Result<PathBuf, String> {
    let path = PathBuf::from(arg_value);

    match path.try_exists() {
        Ok(true) => match path.is_dir() {
            true => Ok(path),
            false => Err("Path is not a directory".to_string()),
        },
        Ok(false) => Err("Path does not exist".to_string()),
        Err(err) => Err(format!("Unable to access path: {}", err)),
    }
}

/// Given an directory path, return all "*.proto" files in it
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `input_dir`: Path to read files from
///
/// returns: Result<impl Iterator<Item=PathBuf>+Sized, Error>
///
fn find_proto_files(input_dir: &Path) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = PathBuf>, Error> {
    fs::read_dir(input_dir).map(|entries| {
        entries
            .map(|entry_r| entry_r.expect("Unable to read directory entry").path())
            .filter(|pathbuf| pathbuf.extension().map_or(false, |e| e == "proto"))
            .map(|pathbuf| Path::new(&pathbuf).to_owned())
    })
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();
    protobuf_codegen::Codegen::new()
        // Use `protoc` parser
        .protoc()
        // .protoc_path(&Path::new("/usr/local/bin/protoc"))
        // All inputs and imports from the inputs must reside in `includes` directories.
        .includes(&[
            args.protos.to_owned(),
            Path::new("/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/").to_owned(),
        ])
        // Inputs must reside in some of include paths.
        // .input("src/protos/apple.proto")
        .inputs(find_proto_files(&args.protos).expect("Unable to find proto files"))
        // Specify output directory
        .out_dir(args.output)
        .run_from_script();
}
```

To generate and publish:

1. `cargo run -p generator -- -p ../proto -o ./mymsgs/src/generated/`
2. `cargo publish -p mymsgs --allow-dirty`

This isn't exactly the cleanest way to do it, because `cargo` won't publish without `--allow-dirty` since the contents of `generated` aren't in git, but I guess it's workable.

I'm open to suggestions - I'm sure this isn't the best possible solution, but it's the one I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks for your posting, Patrick!  I have been thinking about this question as well and your input has been helpful!